# Redirect user and POST param

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to redirect user when page is opened and POST param. I tried this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/redirect/{token}"})
  public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
          @RequestBody Transaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        String post_param = "some_payload";
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url); 
  }
```

Is it possible to redirect the user and POST some param?

Comment: An HTTP redirect always results in a GET request. You can't POST using a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have

```
@GetMapping("/sample_request_mapping_path")
public ModelAndView something() {
    //...
}
```

revise it to

```
@PostMapping(value = "/foo"})
public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token, @RequestBody Transaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String post_param = "some_payload";
    return "redirect:/sample_request_mapping_path"; 
}
```